# Я внёс, но ещё не закоммитил изменения не в ту ветку. Что делать?

Tags: git, git-commit

вот мои ветки

```
aleksey@aleksey:~/Downloads/NTZ/FittingRoom$ git branch -a
develop
feature/addfriendsblock
* feature/getcontacts
remotes/origin/develop
remotes/origin/master
```

Я создал ветку `feature/getcontacts` и работал в ней, потом сделал коммит (работа была не закончена)... Потом я забыл переключиться на `feature/addfriendsblock` и продолжил работать в текущей ветке...

Теперь мне нужно переключиться в ветку `feature/addfriendsblock` и сделать в ней коммит последних дополнений, так как они не относятся к текущей ветке `feature/getcontacts`, но я получаю такое сообщение

```
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.
```

Но мне не нужно коммить последние изменения в текущую ветку они мне нужны в `feature/addfriendsblock` , как это сделать?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Если Вам нужно только закоммитить незакоммиченные данные, но в другую ветку, то можно сделать так. Вначале даем команду `git stash`. Она получит дифф изменений, сохранит его в специальный "карман" и удалит их с ветки. Теперь можно легко переключиться на другую ветку - `git checkout feature/addfriendsblock`. В новой ветке делаем `git stash apply` - теперь с "кармана" будут достаны изменения и применены на новом месте (если что, то в кармане они останутся). Вполне возможно, что будут конфликты - их нужно будет решить. После этого код можно проверить и коммитить.

Comment: Плюс флаг `-k`, если изменения в неотслеживаемых файлах.

Comment: @D-side а зачем `-k` ведь если изменения в неотслеживаемых, то они там и остануться после переключения ветки... или не так?

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko на случай, когда в целевой ветке эти файлы всё же отслеживаются и `git` нервничает переключать :)

Answer (score 2):

`git checkout --merge feature/addfriendsblock`

Потом надо будет провести слияние изменений в файле `Application/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: Ваш ответ с "AndroidManifest.xml" выглядит как то странно. Либо вы оба в одной комнате (или общаетесь по отдельному каналу связи), либо дублика.

Comment: @KoVadim Что странного-то? Имя файла я взял из сообщения об ошибке, которое приведено в вопросе.

Answer (score 0):

Использую в таких случаях возможности TortoiseGit

1. Делаю экспорт изменённых файлов в отдельную папку
2. Делаю hard reset текущей ветки к исходному состоянию
3. Переключаюсь на "правильную" ветку
4. Копирую изменённые файлы поверх
5. Через Working tree changes смотрю изменения в каждом скопированном файле
   Так есть гарантия, что в "правильную" ветку не попадут нежелательные изменения из другой ветки.
   Если в п. 5 в каких-то файлах будет что-то лишнее, с ними вместо перезаписывания уже нужно работать построчно

Comment: Так слишком легко перепутать правки из незакоммиченого изменения с правками из самой ветки. Уж лучше патч использовать. А стэш из принятого ответа это практически тот же патч.

Comment: Да, можно. Поэтому самое важное - это п. 5. Предполагается, что автор помнит, что он делал, что он не делал и вопрос в том, чтобы ему второй раз не вносить те же изменения.
Другой человек, не сможет воспользоваться предлагаемым решением.
Я сталкивался с тем, что при использовании мержа и решения конфликтов получалось дублирование кода. Вина была моя, Merge показывал конфликт. Но дубль был на несколько экранов ниже в TortoiseGitMerge, поэтому я не доверяю мержам и автоматике. Может я "не умею их готовить".

Comment: >Уж лучше патч использовать.
Подскажите, как сделать патч в такой ситуации?

Comment: P.S. Ещё одна вариация моего метода: выкачать отдельно репозиторий, в нём перейти на "правильную" ветку и смотря на Working tree changes в TortoiseGitMerge внести свои изменения копируя поблочно в нужные места вручную. Это если всё совсем плохо и ветка, где делал изменения сильно отличается от "правильной".

Comment: Попробовал все 3 варианта на простом модельном примере. Есть 2 ветки a и b  и file.txt. В ветке a одна строчка "varA=1;", в ветке b "varB=1;". В конце нет перевода строк. Находимся в ветке b. Добавляем строку "myVar=2;", вспоминаем что надо работать в ветке a.

Comment: 1) Через stash получил конфликт.  Соответственно, нужно привлекать средства решения конфликтов. Смущает, что нельзя переключиться на stash, как на обычную ветку и глянуть файл "как есть". Но можно через git archive. Тогда уж проще, мне кажется, создать новую ветку, чем использовать git stash.

Comment: 2) Попробовал свой метод. Перезаписал ветку a файлом с "varB=1; myVar=2". Т.е., как Вы и пишите, превнёс нежелательный правки из "неправильной" ветки. Я вижу эти правки в изменениях и если я знаю, что я этого не писал ("varB=1;"), то откачусь обратно к ветке a и буду уже через средства сравнения файлов вносить только свои изменения в подходящие для них в ветке a места. В ветке b это могли быть совсем другие места.

Comment: 3) Сделал патч через git diff >new.patch. Затем переключился на a и git apply new.patch. Получил "patch does not apply". С опцией --reject получил файл .rej с полным содержимым изменений. Для данного случая непонятно, что дальше делать с патчем. Вручную дифф разбирать?